# failed to converted raw H264 to mp4 wiht FFMPEG and playback it

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I am trying to convert raw video file captured from Cisco EX60 to valid MP4 file.
I use the following command
**ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 25 -i input2 -vcodec libx264 output2.mp4**

and get

```
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[rawvideo @ 0000000000703920] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inac
curate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'input2':
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 630883 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 622080
 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

File 'output2.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.18.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1
080, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.15.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rawvideo @ 00000000007101c0] ****Invalid buffer size, packet size 220075 < expected
 frame_size 3110400
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument****
frame=    5 fps=2.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6514kB time=00:00:00.12 bitrate=444706.9kbi
ts/s
video:6513kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.013209%
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:35.99  size:1334571
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] frame P:4     Avg QP:35.00  size:1333616
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] mb I  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0% 100.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000007115e0] mb P  I16..4: 98.7%  0.0%  1.3%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0
%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
```

with

```
Invalid buffer size, packet size 220075 < expected
     frame_size 3110400
    Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument**
```

inside

When I use just 
**ffmpeg -f h264 -i input -vcodec copy -r 25 outfile.mp4**
It replace initial IFrame with B-frames so I cannot playback it. I can view it with VCL, but not with Windows Media player, for example.
What is wrong with the command?
Thanks
Efim

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264)
```

This is the source video stream, which is already encoded with h264. So it’s unlikely that rawvideo will work. You actually have to decode the stream in order to encode it again.

As for why you can’t play it back in Windows Media Player, please check the [H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). By default the highest profile is used when encoding as h264 which is not compatible with every device and player. For maximum compatibility, add the following options:

```
-profile:v baseline -level 3.0
```